# ntpdate command not found in MacOS Mojave

Tags: bash, macos, macos-mojave, macos-monterey

I have a Bash script who update the time of my mac but since the update of Mojave the command isn't found:

```
ntpdate -u time.apple.com
```

return :

```
ntpdate: command not found
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

See: [How can I tell if my Mac is keeping the clock updated properly?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117864/how-can-i-tell-if-my-mac-is-keeping-the-clock-updated-properly)

TL;DR use `sudo sntp -sS time.apple.com` instead.

Comment: @ACAkgul no, I got 'Operation not permitted' without it.

Comment: Looks like the other question (the one linked from this answer) ended up marked as the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to do this because their vm cannot connect to the update server while trying to install macos on a virtual machine, I switched my network adapter from NAT to bridged and the issue was resolved.

Comment: You saved my life! If you're on VMWare fusion and installing Mojave, changed your network adapter to "Bridged Networking -> Autodetect"