# ntpdate command not found ? MacOS Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I am performing a clean install of MacOS Mavericks on a Macbook Pro 2012 (Mid). While attempting to set the date from the terminal in OSX Utilities, I am confronted with a prompt telling me `command not found` when using both `ntpdate` and `sntp` commands.

I am well aware of the similar questions below, but the answers of neither one helps me.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329222/the-ntpdate-command-was-removed-from-mojave-what-to-use-now?noredirect=1

[ntpdate command not found ? MacOS MOJAVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52548093/ntpdate-command-not-found-macos-mojave)

In other words I have tried the following to no success:

`sudo ntpdate -u time.apple.com`

`sudo sntp -sS time.apple.com`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `man ntpdate` to see if it tells you the PATH to the `ntpdate` as it may not be in root's PATH. Else try looking for it with `find`.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I ended up manually setting the date using:                   **date [MMddHHmmYYYY]** in OSX Utilities. I was then able to successfully install Mavericks. Once installed the above commands for setting date using ntp server are recognized. Still don't know why they were NOT recognized in OSX Utilities terminal.